# Apply images and video responsiveness using incore or contrib drupal8 module?

Tags: 8, media, theming

How can I make the images or videos added to the body or any fields with text format(containing text and images) resized in a responsive fashion?

Answer (score 1):

I love to use the [FitVids](https://www.drupal.org/project/fitvids) module for videos to be automatically responsive on your site.

For images, I think you can manage it with CSS `max-width:100%;` for images. I don't know if there is a better method for that.

Comment: thanks, the whole img is loaded this way so it has an effect on performance